# Javascript inheritance infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I create this block of code in javascript:

```
function Shape() {}
Shape.prototype.name = "Shape";
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {
    result = [];
    if(this.constructor.uber) {
        result[result.length] = this.constructor.uber.toString();
    }
    result[result.length] = this.name;
    return result.join(', ');
}


function twoDShape() {};
twoDShape.prototype = new Shape();
twoDShape.prototype.constructor = twoDShape;

twoDShape.uber = twoDShape.prototype;
twoDShape.name = "twoD Shape";

var a = new twoDShape();
console.log(a.toString());
```

I don't know why but when I run it, firefox is freeze. I've been trying hours to figure it out. And my guess is there should be an infinite loops in my code and it lives somewhere in the if condition, but I didn't find it out. Could someone help me out of this headache.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `this.constructor.uber.toString()` from `Shape.prototype.toString`, `uber` is `twoDShape.prototype` which is a `Shape`, and so that `toString` method is `Shape.prototype.toString` again.

And that causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

well, after trying a fair amount of test, I finally got a clue. And I believe this is a answer for my own question above. Typing: a.constructor.uber.constructor === twoDShape in firefox, it returns true. And that's why it causes infinite loop.

Comment: To be accurate, it's looping in the toString method as per my above answer. The constructors being the same are why this is happening (method calling itself) but isn't actually the cause of the loop in itself.