# Infinite prototypal inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm learning prototypal inheritance in Javascript, and for my understanding I'm trying to use it to send the process into infinite recursive chaining.

My idea of prototypal inheritance is that an object (which is a function) holds prototype link. Any instance of that object points to it. So if I say instance.someproperty it looks into the prototype chain of the parent object.

Assuming this, If I just point function prototype list to itself, it should go into infinite loop when object tries to access some property.

```
 var p = function(){};

 p.prototype = p;
 // I also tried p.prototype = new p();

 var q = new p();

 // and now when I say q.something, it should never be able to find it.
```

I want to know why this doesn't work and how can I make it to go into infinite loop.

Comment: The prototype function itself has nothing to do with property lookup.

Comment: for learning purpose? Is everything you do in your life is useful to you?

Comment: @jfriend It's okay to not be a hacker. But I wouldn't knock people for having the inclination.

Comment: @jfriend00 - By "hacker" I'm going on the more classic definition of someone who takes an axe to things to understand how they work. Prototype is more of a surrogate lookup mechanism than a true inheritance mechanic. Understanding that has played key role in my everyday-use/implementation of it when it comes up. It's not about breaking stuff but rather understanding why it doesn't break.

Comment: I think what jfriend meant is that you might teach him a new trick by explaining a valid reason as to why you would want this. Learning purposes is a valid reason but not a practical one. I ask all the time why this or that hoping I missed something and maybe learn something new, its not to insult but to clarify. In his question as to why he also mentions the obvious disadvantage of creating such a loop

Comment: I think he asked why you'd want the chicken  to cross the road when the real question was "Holy crap! How did it end up getting to the other side?"

Comment: @jfriend00 - man so much of negativity. people here are just interested in learning, if you cannot add value to the conversation atleast don't try to demean it.

Comment: @sublime - geez.  I asked a simple question about why because that is something I like to understand before I contribute and I feel like I am being attacked for wanting to understand why.  I'm perfectly fine if others want to pursue this.  Bye.

Comment: @ErikReppen I now see your point, read the question again it's "why would this code not cause an infinite loop?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using more common style:

```
function P(){};
P.prototype = P;
```

In ECMA-262, the [internal prototype property](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) is denoted by `[[Prototype]]`.

Assigning a different object to *P.prototype* does not modify *P*'s `[[Prototype]]`, so its inheritance chain remains as:

```
P : P[[Prototype]] -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Given that *P* and *P.prototype* both point to the same object, the `[[prototype]]` chain of an instance of *P* is:

```
p : p[[Prototype]] -> P : P[[Prototype]] -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

so no endless loop.

Without the assignment to *P.prototype*, *p*'s prototype chain would have been:

```
p : p[[Prototype]] -> P.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

To get an endless loop, you can assign an object to its own `__proto__` property (the public way to access `[[Prototype]]`) in those browsers that support it, but I'm not sure that's a good idea, Firefox throws:

```
"TypeError: cyclic __proto__ value".
```

Comment: so how do I get it in endless loop?

Comment: see this, hopefully it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970308/javascript-inheritance-infinite-loop and/or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720659/javascript-inheritance-infinite-loop-when-using-superclass-function

Comment: @OneKitten : I tried that too :) I thought it was a chrome thing, so I did the same thing but in node.js and got the same error. Later realized that node.js is v8 as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, to your first question:

```
var p = function(){};

p.prototype = p;
// I also tried p.prototype = new p();

var q = new p();
```

In the first one, all you're doing when you create an instance of `p` is setting the prototype to the function `p` itself, which is an object in its own right (with properties such as `length`, `prototype`, etc.). Its actual internal prototype is `Function.prototype`, which in turn has a prototype of `Object.prototype`.

The second one is slightly different -- close, but no cigar. When you're assigning `new p()` to `p.prototype`, the `prototype` property has not been set yet, so you're just going to get the original value of the `prototype` property as the instance's internal prototype.

---

Moving on to your second question. I don't actually see why you'd do this, as every property would be shadowed by its own instance property.

Even if you were allowed to (no browsers do), there would be no point.

Consider this:

```
var a = { b: 1 };
a.__proto__ = a;
```

Let's assume that this works, ignore the fact that this throws a TypeError in all browsers (which is specified for browsers in Annex B of the upcoming ES6 spec).

If you were to access the property `b`, you'd never go up the prototype chain.

If you attempted to access a non-existent property, an implementation (if it allowed for such a thing) could either go up the prototype chain, back to itself recursively, or recognise that the property would never be found and return undefined.

Of course, there is the situation where there are multiple objects involved:

```
var a = { x: 1 };
var b = { y: 2 };
b.__proto__ = a;
a.__proto__ = b;
```

However, this is ridiculously stupid and of no practical use (if permitted in the first place -- it isn't).