# Multiple prototypical inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have 2 base classes, say `ParentClass1` and `ParentClass2`. Now I want to do multiple prototypical inheritance to `ChildClass`.

With a **single parent class**, I had my code as follows.

```js
var ParentClass = function() {

};

ParentClass.prototype.greetUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hi. Hello,', name);
};

var ChildClass = function(name) {
  this.greetUser(name);
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

var obj = new ChildClass('John');
// Hi. Hello, John
```

---

And now when I have to inherit from **2 parent classes**, I tried the following code.

```js
var ParentClass1 = function() {

};

ParentClass1.prototype.greetUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hi. Hello,', name);
};

var ParentClass2 = function() {

};

ParentClass2.prototype.askUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hey, how are you,', name);
};

var ChildClass = function(name) {
  this.askUser(name);
  this.greetUser(name);
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass1.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass2.prototype);

var obj = new ChildClass('John');
// Error.
```

But this seems like, this will only accept the last mentioned `Object.create()`.

So later, It tried switching the second `Object.create()` to `Object.assign()`, and then it worked fine.

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass1.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype = Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, ParentClass2.prototype);
```

But my concern is `Object.assign()` is doing **a clone**. So is that the right way to do it? Or are there any better alternatives?

Sorry for making this question lengthy. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**NOTE:** I had a brief look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145203/infinite-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Comment: `Object.assign` does not do a deep clone. It is shallow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very useful to do two assignments to the `prototype` property, as the last one will overwrite the first. You can do like this, since [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) accepts more arguments:

```
Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, ParentClass1.prototype, ParentClass2.prototype);
```

Note that `Object.assign` performs a *shallow* copy. That a copy has to be made is sure: you need a prototype object that is different from both other prototypes: the union of both. So inevitably you need to somehow copy the members of the parent prototypes into your target prototype object.

### Some caveats:

#### 1. `Object.assign` makes a shallow copy

Since `Object.assign` performs a shallow copy, you might get into cases where you interfere with the parent prototype. This might be what you want or do not want.

Example:

```js
var ParentClass1 = function() {

};

ParentClass1.prototype.userList = [];
ParentClass1.prototype.addUser = function(name) {
    this.userList.push(name);
};

var ParentClass2 = function() {

};

ParentClass2.prototype.askUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hey, how are you,', name);
};

var ChildClass = function(name) {
  this.askUser(name);
};

Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, ParentClass1.prototype, ParentClass2.prototype);

var p = new ParentClass1('Parent');
var obj = new ChildClass('John');
obj.addUser('Tim'); // Added to child, but
console.log(p.userList); // now parent also has Tim...
```

#### 2. `Object.assign` only copies enumerable properties

This means that in some cases you will not get the properties you had hoped for. Say you wanted to inherit also from `Array.prototype`, then you would want your child object to have a `length` property, but since it is not enumerable, you will not get it with `Object.assign`:

```js
var ParentClass2 = function() {

};

ParentClass2.prototype.askUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hey, how are you,', name);
};

var ChildClass = function(name) {
  this.askUser(name);
};

Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, Array.prototype, ParentClass2.prototype);

var obj = new ChildClass('John');
console.log(obj.length); // undefined
console.log(Array.prototype.length); // 0
```

#### 3. `Object.assign` executes getters

`Object.assign` cannot copy getters. Instead it executes them to retrieve the value for the copy. Executing code on the parent prototype may have effects (by design of that getter) on the state of the parent prototype. This might be undesired behaviour in the context of this copy.

Secondly, the value of the getter can be the result of some calculation and state of the object, returning different values each time it is referenced. But `object.assign` will only reference it once, and then create a property that always has that single value. See the effect in this example:

```js
var ParentClass1 = function() {

};

// Define a getter on the prototype which returns a
// random number between 0 and 999, every time it is referenced:
Object.defineProperty(ParentClass1.prototype, 'randomNumber', { 
    get: function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 1000); 
    }, 
    enumerable: true 
});

var ParentClass2 = function() {};

ParentClass2.prototype.askUser = function(name) {
    console.log('Hey, how are you,', name);
};

var ChildClass = function(name) {
  this.askUser(name);
};

Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, ParentClass1.prototype, ParentClass2.prototype);

var p = new ParentClass1('Parent');
var obj = new ChildClass('John');
console.log('different:');
console.log(p.randomNumber);
console.log(p.randomNumber);
console.log(p.randomNumber);
console.log('always same:');
console.log(obj.randomNumber);
console.log(obj.randomNumber);
console.log(obj.randomNumber);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### Further reading

The concept of combining multiple prototypes into a new one is often coined ["mixin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). Here are some related Q&A:

- [How to use mixins properly in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632298/how-to-use-mixins-properly-in-javascript)
- [Javascript mixins when using the module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631517/javascript-mixins-when-using-the-module-pattern)
- [How to add mixins to ES6 javascript classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247434/how-to-add-mixins-to-es6-javascript-classes)
- [What's the difference between mixin() and extend() in Javascript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506210/whats-the-difference-between-mixin-and-extend-in-javascript-libraries)

Comment: I was asking, is this the right way to do multiple inheritance on prototypical inheritance? Or is there any better way?

Comment: There are different ways of doing it, and this is one of them. If this suits your needs, it is just fine.